# Might as well Vs should

Tags: grammar

Could you please tell me the difference between:

(1) The deadline is today, but you **might as well** send it in anyway—they may still accept it.

(2) The deadline is today, but you **should** send it in anyway—they may still accept it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **may/might as well** do something, you decide to do it without having a strong reason, because there is no better alternative.

In your example, if you don't send 'it' in there is no chance of its being accepted. If you do send it, there is at least a small chance. So, sending it is 'as good as' not sending it (or slightly better!).

If you tell someone they **should** do something, there *is* a strong reason to do it.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the version with “should”?

Comment: I have added a sentence to my answer.